# Can a React prop type be defined recursively?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose we're defining a React class that will display a tree.

```
React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        tree: treeType
    },
    render: function () {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Here's a definition of `treeType` that obviously doesn't work but hopefully illustrates what I'm trying to express.

```
var treeType = React.PropTypes.shape({
    value: React.PropTypes.string,
    children: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(treeType)
})
```

Is there a way to let the type refer to itself lazily so this can work?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I was looking for the same thing -> https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5676

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A React prop type is just a function, so it can be referenced lazily like this:

```
function lazyFunction(f) {
    return function () {
        return f.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

var lazyTreeType = lazyFunction(function () { 
    return treeType;
});

var treeType = React.PropTypes.shape({
    value: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    children: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(lazyTreeType)
})
```

The rest of the code for a complete working example ([also available as a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qp5dzvs7/)):

```
function hasChildren(tree) {
    return !!(tree.children && tree.children.length);
}

var Tree = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        tree: treeType
    },
    render: function () {
        return this.renderForest([this.props.tree], '');
    },
    renderTree: function (tree, key) {
        return <li className="tree" key={key}>
            <div title={key}>{tree.value}</div>
            {hasChildren(tree) &&
                this.renderForest(tree.children, key)}
        </li>;
    },
    renderForest: function (trees, key) {
        return <ol>{trees.map(function (tree) {
            return this.renderTree(tree, key + ' | ' + tree.value);
        }.bind(this))}</ol>;
    }
});

var treeOfLife = { value: "Life", children: [
    {value: "Animal", children: [
        {value: "Dog"},
        {value: "Cat"}
    ]},
    {value: "Plant"}
]};

React.render(
    <Tree tree={treeOfLife}/>,
    document.getElementById('tree'));
```

Screenshot of the result:

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: Some reason for not use just:
    var lazyTreeType = function () {
        return treeType.apply(this, arguments);
    };

Comment: @FelipeT. I'm also curious about this

Comment: @FelipeT. I think there's nothing wrong with the function you suggested. The answer's approach is probably only for comprehensibility and a bit more generic.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another approach, courtesy of [jethrolarson on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5676#issuecomment-287148364):

Given the recursive component `Tree`

```
import React from 'react';

const Tree = ({treeData}) => (
    <div>
        {treeData.nodeName}{' '}
        {treeData.children.map(subTree => (
            <Tree treeData={subTree} />
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

that takes a tree data structure like the one below

```
                Root
                /  \
           Child1   Child2
          /     \        \
     GChild1   GChild2   GChild3
```

(as code:

```
const treeData = {
    nodeName: "Root",
    children: [
        {
            nodeName: "Child1",
            children: [
                {nodeName: "GChild1"},
                {nodeName: "GChild2"},
            ]
        },
        {
            nodeName: "Child2",
            children: [
                {nodeName: "GChild3"},
            ]
        },
    ]
};
```

),

**the `propTypes` for `Tree` can be defined as:**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const treeDataShape = {
    nodeName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
treeDataShape.children = PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape(treeDataShape));

Tree.propTypes = {
    treeData: PropTypes.shape(treeDataShape),
};
```

Note how all of the references to `treeDataShape` refer to the same object. Defining `children` after the object is created lets you recursively reference the same object.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work out for me, but the reference sharing strategy did. +1

Answer (score 0):

I created recursive prop types something like this and it worked for me. Let me know if it works for you as well. lazyTreeType function will be called as many times as there is a sub in the object.

```
const lazyTreeType = () => some_props;
const some_props= PropTypes.shape({
  date: PropTypes.string,
  updated: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  sub: PropTypes.arrayOf(lazyTreeType),
  type: PropTypes.string,
});

const component_proptype = PropTypes.shape({
  id: PropTypes.string,
  sub: PropTypes.arrayOf(some_props),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it:

```js
MenuItem.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    children(...args) {
        return PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape(this)).apply(this, args);
    },
};
```

Doing it like this there is no need to create extra lazy functions.