# How i can use recursion function in React.PropTypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, dry, react-proptypes

For example, i have this proptypes pattern:

```
pages: pt.arrayOf(pt.shape({
        id: pt.string.isRequired,
        prevId: pt.string,
        nextId: pt.string,
        pages: pt.arrayOf(pt.shape({
                    id: pt.string.isRequired,
                    prevId: pt.string,
                    nextId: pt.string,
                    pages: -//-//- (same array)
        })),
    }))
```

How i can make it more in DRY style? I just starting learn JS and React.

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32063297/can-a-react-prop-type-be-defined-recursively ?